# Create super user using Railway CLI

Tags: django, django-deployment, railway

I'm trying to create a super user for my Django project using Railway CLI.

I've installed Railway CLI and tried:

1-step
`railway login`
**Successfully logged in**

2-step
`railway link`
**Linked my project**

3-step
`railway run python manage.py createsuperuser`

But unexpectedly, I've got this error: `No such file or directory (os error 2)`.

My Django project is working awesome on the railway, but I can't do this task.